# XSLT - Checking the existence of a child element attribute in XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose I have something like the following in an xml file:

```
<student name="bob">
    <grades exam1="98" exam2="53"/>
    <status>GOOD</status>
</student>
```

and in my xslt i have something like:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(student/status[text()='GOOD']) and not(student/grades/@exam1)">
        <!--passed code here-->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!--otherwise code here-->
</xsl:choose>
```

Now the first part of the conditional works (ie. checking if the status is GOOD) but the second part doesn't (ie. checking if the student doesn't have a grade for exam1) So to get into the "passed code here" section, I want to only look at those students who have the following:

```
<student name="mary">
    <grades exam2="53"/>
    <status>GOOD</status>
</student>
```

So there is NO exam1 attribute under grades. I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong in the conditional statement given above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the context of your `<xsl:choose>` instruction? And why do you need an `<xsl:choose>` instruction at all? Why don't you just select the students that meet the criteria? It would be much better if you posted an example of input with 2 or more students, and the expected output of transforming that example.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following document:

```
<root>
    <student name="bob">
        <grades exam1="98" exam2="53"/>
        <status>GOOD</status>
    </student>
    <student name="mary">
        <grades exam2="53"/>
        <status>GOOD</status>
    </student>
</root>
```

These two templates will match one or the other.  This would be a better approach than using `xsl:choose` all over the place.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/root/student[status='GOOD' and grades/@exam1]">
      asdf      
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/student[status='GOOD' and not(grades/@exam1)]">
      fdsa
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

This results in:

```
asdf

fdsa
```